# Event Handler onclick not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling

as an assignment of my university, I made this simple Static Log-In Form using JavaScript and HTML, but there is one Even Handler onclick which is not working, I tried all possible solutions, I tried to sue  tag to make button as well, but still its not working. Kindly help me where i am doing mistake. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test File </title>

    <script>

        function checkEmailField()
        {
            if (document.username.sender.value.length < 1)
            {
            window.alert("Caution! You did not enter your Email");
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="pink">

    <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <b> <h1> Fill the following form to log in: </h1> </b>

                    <form name="logIn" method="post" action="sendMailScriptURL">
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Email: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="username" size="50"> <br> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Password: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="password" size ="50"> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Logging in from: </b> </td>
                                <td>    
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="campus"> Campus <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="home"> Home                      
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I am using: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="OS" size="1">
                                        <option value="Windows" selected> Windows
                                        <option value="Linux/UNIX"> LINUX/UNIX
                                        <option value="Mac OSX"> Mac OSX
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I have: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Computer"> Computer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Mobile"> Mobile <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Printer"> Printer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Scanner"> Scanner
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <button onclick="checkEmailField()"> Log In </button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check in browser  console for error

Comment: The code is fine?

Comment: seems correct  .. but you have checked the browser  console for errors?

Comment: Yeah, just checked it now, it gave me the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined
    at checkEmailField (test.html:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:67)

Comment: You are accessing to elemen (username)  in wrong way  .. i have posted a brief answer as a suggestion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two issue here: the first is in the way you try to access your email field's value in your "checkEmailField" function. You want to access the forms attribute of the document object, then your particular form, and finally the field you want. I'm not sure why you have "sender" in there too - I'm guessing that's a typo.

The second issue is that you have only this one button in your form. By default, and to be nice, browsers will then use this lone button as a "submit" button. When you hit the button, the form will submit no matter what. You want to prevent the submit if the email is empty. You do this by returning false in your "checkEmailField" function and by returning the function's return value in your onclick handler.

Try this version instead:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test File </title>

    <script>

        function checkEmailField()
        {
            if (document.forms.logIn.username.value.length < 1)
            {
            window.alert("Caution! You did not enter your Email");
            return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="pink">

    <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <b> <h1> Fill the following form to log in: </h1> </b>

                    <form name="logIn" method="post" action="sendMailScriptURL">
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Email: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="username" size="50"> <br> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Password: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="password" size ="50"> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Logging in from: </b> </td>
                                <td>    
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="campus"> Campus <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="home"> Home                      
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I am using: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="OS" size="1">
                                        <option value="Windows" selected> Windows
                                        <option value="Linux/UNIX"> LINUX/UNIX
                                        <option value="Mac OSX"> Mac OSX
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I have: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Computer"> Computer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Mobile"> Mobile <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Printer"> Printer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Scanner"> Scanner
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <button onclick="return checkEmailField();"> Log In </button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, this is what I wanted. Actually I was looking for a way without using any variable or any other thing. Because, our professor taught us the topic of using functions only and I did not want to use any other part of JavaScript to make it done. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Place your javascript code before the ending of `<body>` tag, that should fix the problem of the js function call.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test File </title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="pink">

    <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <b> <h1> Fill the following form to log in: </h1> </b>

                    <form name="logIn" method="post" action="sendMailScriptURL">
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Email: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="username" size="50"> <br> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Password: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="password" size ="50"> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Logging in from: </b> </td>
                                <td>    
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="campus"> Campus <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="home"> Home                      
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I am using: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="OS" size="1">
                                        <option value="Windows" selected> Windows
                                        <option value="Linux/UNIX"> LINUX/UNIX
                                        <option value="Mac OSX"> Mac OSX
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I have: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Computer"> Computer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Mobile"> Mobile <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Printer"> Printer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Scanner"> Scanner
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <button onclick="checkEmailField()"> Log In </button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <script>

        function checkEmailField()
        {
            if (document.username.sender.value.length < 1)
            {
            window.alert("Caution! You did not enter your Email");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.username` won't match anything, so you'll get an error: `Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined`. You'll have to look it up in the DOM using a traversal method. The easiest is probably to add an `id` to the username input field: `input id="username" name="username"` and then use `document.getElementById` (or you could use `document.querySelector`). Here's a quick jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tztyky6g/

Answer (score 0):

Change the code  `document.username.sender.value.length < 1`

**To**
`var email = document.forms[0].elements["username"].value;`

`document` object contains a `forms` property, Since in this HTML you have 1 form, so you can access it like `document.forms[0]` and then you need to access the `username` **input** which can be done using `document.forms[0].elements["username"]`

Also, you are not creating any property `username` on `document` object so if you try access `document.username` it will return `undefined` as no property name `username` exists in `document` object.

**Complete Code:**

```js
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test File </title>

    <script>

        function checkEmailField()
        {
            var email = document.forms[0].elements["username"].value;
            if (email.length < 1)
            {
                 window.alert("Caution! You did not enter your Email");
                 return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="pink">

    <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <b> <h1> Fill the following form to log in: </h1> </b>

                    <form name="logIn" method="post" action="sendMailScriptURL">
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Email: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="username" size="50"> <br> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Password: </b> </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="password" size ="50"> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> Logging in from: </b> </td>
                                <td>    
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="campus"> Campus <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="from" value="home"> Home                      
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I am using: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="OS" size="1">
                                        <option value="Windows" selected> Windows
                                        <option value="Linux/UNIX"> LINUX/UNIX
                                        <option value="Mac OSX"> Mac OSX
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <b> I have: </b> </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Computer"> Computer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Mobile"> Mobile <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Printer"> Printer <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="have" value="Scanner"> Scanner
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td> <button onclick="checkEmailField()"> Log In </button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Agalo this works perfectly but I was looking for the version which was done without using any variables. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you can replace the variable in the single statement if you need it that way only. Using meaningful name makes it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl change  you function accessing to the element in proper  way

```
 function checkEmailField()
    {
         var myElem = document.getElementsByName('username');
        if (myElem[0].value.length < 1)
        {
        window.alert("Caution! You did not enter your Email");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or I could do it as
`document.forms.username.value.length <1`?

Comment: I have update the answer  getElements return a collection so you need  the firts elem

Comment: thanks it worked but I was looking for one without usage of variable, and someone posted that answer above. By teh way still thanks a lot. You actually told me how to see the errors by using Console. This was new for me :D thanks